# Assembly macro print error

Tags: assembly, macros

so I've been trying to use some macros to print some messages in assembly(I'm using TASM as a compiler) and it went good until one point. I have to read a string with numbers from [0...9] and compute the sum of the even numbers. The problem is that once I press enter after I finish inputing the string, the program doesn't do anything and it just blocks. Can you help me solve the problem?
Here is the code:

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
MSG1 DB 0DH, 0AH, 'PLEASE INPUT YOUR STRING', '$'
MSG2 DB 0DH, 0AH, 'THE SUM IS', '$'
NEWLINE DB 0DH, 0AH, '$'
TOTAL DB ?
DATA ENDS

WRITE MACRO MSG
MOV AH, 09H
LEA DX, MSG
INT 21H
ENDM WRITE

WRITE2 MACRO NR
MOV AH, 02H
MOV DL, NR
INT 21H
ENDM WRITE2

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START PROC FAR
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

WRITE MSG1
WRITE NEWLINE


MOV AH,0AH
INT 21H ;READ INPUT

MOV SI,0002H ;INDEX USED TO ACCESS DS CONTENT, 0002h is where string begins
MOV DX,0 ;this is where I store the sum


MOV BL,2 ;used for even nr test
MOV CL,BYTE PTR DS:[0001] ;number of elements stored in the string

L:
    XOR AX,AX
    CMP BYTE PTR DS:[SI],20H ;check if current position is a space(' ')
    JE SPACE

    MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[SI] ;not a space, now we check if it's even
    SUB AL,30H
    DIV BL ;we divide by 2
    CMP AH,0 ;get the mod result(0 even, 1 odd)
    JNE SPACE
    CALL SUM 


    SPACE: INC SI
    LOOP L

MOV TOTAL,DL

WRITE MSG2
WRITE2 TOTAL

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
RET 
START ENDP

PROC SUM
ADD DL, BYTE PTR DS:[SI] ;ds content, where the string is stored
SUB DL, 30H ;ascii to digit
RET
SUM ENDP

CODE ENDS 
END START
```

Comment: [`MOV AH,0AH` `INT 21H`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-a.html) requires pointer to input buffer in `ds:dx`. You don't set that, so it's not clear where the input is stored (somewhere in memory, probably overwriting something else). Then you do `mov si,2` and use that as pointer into memory, may technically even target the input by accident, if the `dx` was zero during `int 21h,ah=0ah`, but that's not how one writes readable assembly source, check some SO answers for [emu8086] and [x86-16] and even [x86] tags, to get some "taste" for what a "good style" is and how to improve.

Comment: Things like you used are rather for code-golfing (like 256B intros), when you know what you are doing, and you still put all the assumptions/tricks description at least into comments, so the source reader can easily understand how/why the code works. ... and for programming in assembly you need debugger, for DOS common options are "codeview" from MS (cv.exe), "turbo debugger" from Borland (if you happen to be owner of TASM), or even DOS's "debug.exe" which is not so easy to use (more like command line), but some people like it. Or you may use external debugger of virtual machines (BOCHS).

Comment: I added some comments to make to code look more readable. @Ped7g the turbo debugger won't let me get back in the debugger after I introduce the string.

Comment: That sounds like you had `ds:dx` pointing into your code, which got overwritten by string, removing the breakpoint. Verify the arguments for the `int 21h` ahead of executing it, whether they point to valid input buffer (if you somehow missed it, *you* must provide the input buffer, not DOS).

Comment: I changed to `BH` to compute the sum and it works now. The problem now is that I can't introduce more than 12 characters in the buffer. If I do `1 2 3 4 5 6` it's fine, it gives me the correct sum, but if I go `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` it does nothing.

Comment: it can not do "nothing" as long as your computer works. Indeed it does something. Probably something you don't want, but who knows, as I'm not going to debug such mess, you still don't provide input buffer for the input, just let it accidentally overwrite your first `MSG1` string with first value `13` working as max input limit, so your "accidental input buffer" is 13 bytes long only. By entering exactly 13 bytes ("1.. 7") you don't have newline `13` as last char of input, like there was before with shorter strings. If you would use debugger, and check your memory content, you would see that.

Comment: I mean, you have bugs/problems/bad-taste constructions almost on every other line, so I'm not even trying to build answer for you. If you are interested, I may create the same task by my own code, completely ignoring yours, so you can compare the sources, but that's usually considered bad kind of answer on SO. While your question is too-broad / low-debugging-effort, but your skills look to be so low at the moment, that its probably one of best you can post. Don't worry, just keep reading the tutorials/books and try again and again, ASM takes time and effort, but it will come to you. :)

Comment: And not having last char of input as enter is probably not a problem in your case either, as you use the input length in `cl` for looping through all characters of input, so this part may work well, without debugging (in PC or in head) I don't see why "1..7" input results in different behaviour.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, it was the input buffer, it was set to '0D', which is 13 in decimal. I changed its value and now everything seems to work fine. If you can, I would really like to see a less bug-ish version of this problem, but again, only if you have the time. Thanks anyway for all the help.

Comment: I probably figured out your "it does nothing" comment regarding maximum length input, if you are using dosbox, see my update in answer, it really behaves sort of stupid (didn't expect it), once you fill the input buffer, it will not accept `<enter>` key any more, you must delete last character first with backspace, then you can enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in comments by OP, here is my variant of the same task, source is for TASM assembler (I have TASM 4.1 and TLINK 7.1.30.1):

```
; I will use the "simplified" TASM model+segment definitions starting with dot
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 500h
.DATA

NewLineText LABEL BYTE
    DB  13, 10, '$'
InputPrompt LABEL BYTE
    DB  "Please input your string:$"
AnswerLabel LABEL BYTE
    DB  "The sum of even digits is: $"
InputBuffer LABEL BYTE      ; input buffer for DOS service int 21h,0Ah
    DB  80, 0, 80 DUP (0)   ; max 79+enter characters
AsciiSumResult LABEL BYTE
    DB  "000$"              ; 79*8 = 632 is maximum possible result
    ; plus it also contains dollar terminator for printing by DOS 21h,09h

.CODE
.386
    ASSUME CS:@CODE, DS:@DATA

Start:
    ; set up ds to point to .data segment
    mov     ax,@DATA
    mov     ds,ax
    ; print input prompt
    call    PrintNewLine
    lea     dx,[InputPrompt]
    call    PrintDollarTerminatedString
    call    PrintNewLine
    ; run DOS service for input string (80 chars max)
    mov     ah,0Ah
    lea     dx,[InputBuffer]
    int     21h
    ; sum even digits from input
    lea     si,[InputBuffer+2]  ; pointer to first input character
    movzx   cx,BYTE PTR [si-1]  ; length of entered input
SummingLoop:
    lodsb                   ; al = next input character (from ds:[si++])
    ; only ASCII digits are valid input
    cmp     al,'9'
    ja      NotDigit
    sub     al,'0'          ; does both compare the value and
    jb      NotDigit        ; convert it from ASCII digit to integer
    ; here AL=0..9, test if the value is even
    test    al,1            ; if it is not divisible by 2 (odd)
    jnz     NotDigit        ; first bit is one (not zero)
    ; add the value to the ASCII (!!!) sum
    ; (to avoid conversion from multi-digit integer to string later)
    add     [AsciiSumResult+2],al   ; add value to last digit, check overflow
    cmp     BYTE PTR [AsciiSumResult+2],'9'
    jbe     NotDigit        ; no overflow, just continue
    ; adjust result (subtract 10 from last digit, and +1 to middle one)
    add     WORD PTR [AsciiSumResult+1],-10*256+1
    ; check overflow on middle digit
    cmp     BYTE PTR [AsciiSumResult+1],'9'
    jbe     NotDigit        ; no overflow, just continue
    ; adjust result (subtract 10 from middle digit, and +1 to first one)
    add     WORD PTR [AsciiSumResult],-10*256+1
    ; first digit can't overflow (max possible result is 632) => no check
NotDigit:
    dec     cx
    jnz     SummingLoop     ; validate+sum all input characters
    ; output sum, show the label text first
    call    PrintNewLine
    lea     dx,[AnswerLabel]
    call    PrintDollarTerminatedString
    ; output sum, show the value (skip leading zeroes)
    lea     si,[AsciiSumResult]
    cmp     BYTE PTR [si],'0'
    jnz     OutputSum       ; first digit is non-zero, print it
    inc     si
    cmp     BYTE PTR [si],'0'
    jnz     OutputSum       ; second digit is non-zero, print it
    inc     si              ; print third digit (even when zero)
OutputSum:
    ; leading zeroes skipped, SI is pointing to result sum string
    mov     dx,si
    call    PrintDollarTerminatedString
    ; terminate application
    mov     ah,4Ch
    int     21h

; --- helper procedures ---

; ds:dx = pointer of string to print, modifies ax
PrintDollarTerminatedString PROC
    mov     ah,9
    int     21h
    ret
PrintDollarTerminatedString ENDP

; prints new line, modifies ax, dx
PrintNewLine PROC
    lea     dx,[NewLineText]
    jmp     PrintDollarTerminatedString
PrintNewLine ENDP

END Start
```

To build use simple: `TASM <filename>` `TLINK <filename>`, EXE file should be produced without warning.

Sample output (from "dosemu", as "dosbox" doesn't support copying in text modes, while in "dosemu" copy/paste works as in ordinary X-window application (I use linux as OS)):

```
D:\asm\tasm>so_sum

Please input your string:
123456 1 2 3 4 5 6
The sum of even digits is: 24
```

---

Another funny thing about dosbox vs dosemu, in dosbox it is possible to enter 80 characters into input, but you can't hit enter when you did reach maximum characters amount (that is probably source of OP's *"it does nothing"* comment with `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` input). Once you delete the 80th character with backspace, enter works, and code continues.

In dosemu the emulated DOS allows only 79 characters to be entered, keeping the 80th byte reserved for enter-only, which looks lot more logical behaviour.

---

The source code is written mostly in simple straightforward way, except being a bit tricky around summing the digits. It is summing them not as integer value, but as ASCII string in memory (resolving the overflow of ASCII digit like '9'+5 => should turn into '4', and send +1 to digit on left). And the overflow adjusting is using the little-endian encoding of `WORD` values to hit two digits at the same time with `ADD` instruction, doing `-10` to the digit on right, and `+1` to the digit on left.

If you paid attention to how values are encoded in computer in bits/bytes/words/etc.. you should decipher it, it's not that advanced, but would be undecipherable for somebody not understanding how values are encoded in computer and memory.

And the odd/even test is of course NOT using `DIV` instruction. Integer values in computer are already encoded in bits as "binary", so testing first bit (it may be encoding value 2<sup>0</sup> = 1 when being interpreted as integer) is decisive for even/odd test, and it is much more simpler+faster for CPU to test value of bit, than calculating division arithmetic.